# Get the data from the given specific date to 'now' by the interval of 15 minutes

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader, data-retrieval

Hi I am developing an application to retrieve data from one database server to another in C# Visual Studio 2010.

There is a requirement that data should be retrieve from the database by software installation date means a specific date to now means current time.

There is also one more condition that when we get the oldest record like `2010-03-05 16:30:23`, the next record and the first record difference should be 15 minutes like next record should be `2010-03-05 16:45:23`. Database having records per minute.

I have been tried the below but it's not fulfilling the requirement.

```
try
 {
   var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.sConstr);
   var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from RAW_S001T01 where Date_Time >='" + time + "'", con);
   con.Open();
   var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   var count = 0;
   while (dr.Read())
   {
    var Date = (dr["Date_Time"].ToString());
    var temp = Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var UTime=time.Split(':');
    string tempa = UTime[1].Substring(0, 2);
    time = temp +int.Parse("15");
    MessageBox.Show(time);
   }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  MessageBox.Show(@"Error.",ex.ToString());
 }
```

How can we resolve this?

Comment: So which part exactly is going wrong?  What is it doing or not doing?

Comment: It seems like the setting of the new "cmd" is outside of your while loop, so it never gets the new time.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I am just getting all the records by the specific date to now. I want them in 15 minutes interval time

Comment: OK, so how do you want them partitioned, what's your data scheme?

Comment: Like in my question if my oldest data is of time '2010-03-05 16:30:23' then in next loop run next record should be of time '2010-03-05 16:45:23'. My data scheme is of electricity meter reader which reads the power usage per minute.

Comment: Well, your one loop doesn't use time as a parameter at all, which is ok, it just means that you'll be pulling the data out (maybe one row at a time), checking the time and then storing it someplace.  How are you storing your data (and yes I mean temporarily in the program before you go to the processing/displaying part of your program)?

Comment: dr.Read() gets you a row, but you're not doing anything with that row except taking the time out of it.

Comment: Actually inserting the retrieved data into another data severer is little bit big coding, so here to understand I just eliminated that coding and took the data in 'MessageBox.Show'

Comment: Ok, I gave the process, but it's hard to be specific since you're not doing any partitioning in the code you show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this out:** 
 just modify your while loop and use this code.

```
var Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Date_Time"]);
Date = Date.AddMinutes(15);
MessageBox.Show(Date.ToString());
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just set the 15 minutes later time in a variable (as per Abhishek's answer).

Then process all items less than that time.  When you find an item with a time greater than that time, update that time (add another 15 minutes) and redirect the output to the next section of your data structure.  Keep looping until you finish.